# The visualization of high-dimensional input for two-class classification in SVM

Tags: visualization, svm, libsvm

I am trying to find a way to visualize the data with high-dimensional input for two-class classification in SVM, before analysis to decide which kernel to use. In documents online, the visualization of data is given only for two dimensional inputs (I mean two attributes).

Another question rises: What if I have multi-class and more than two attributes?

Answer (score 1):

To visualize, the data should be represented by 3 or less dimension.

1. Simply `PCA` can be applied to reduce dimension.
2. use `pre-image` using MDS.

   - refer to a paper **The pre-image problem in kernel methods** and **its matlab code** in  http://www.cse.ust.hk/~jamesk/publication.html