# Visualizing high-dimensional SVM with SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, svm

I am experimenting with **Support Vector Machine** (SVM) using Python's `SciKit-Learn` package.
I want to visualize my SVM boundaries and margins, in order to get the feeling of what's going on and how the margins look like. When the data is 2-dimensional, `dim=2`, the following code produce a very good visualization.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay

kernel='rbf'

np.random.seed(0)
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=40, centers=4, random_state=6, n_features=dim)

# class sklearn.svm.SVC(*, C=1.0, kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma='scale', 
# coef0=0.0, shrinking=True, probability=False, tol=0.001, cache_size=200, 
# class_weight=None, verbose=False, max_iter=-1, decision_function_shape='ovr', 
# break_ties=False, random_state=None)[source]
clf = SVC(kernel=kernel, degree=3, C=1, decision_function_shape='ovr', probability=True)

clf.fit(X, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

disp = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
        clf,
        X,
        response_method="predict",
        cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,
        alpha=0.8,
        ax=ax,
        xlabel="x1",
        ylabel="x2",
    )
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors="k")
ax.set_title(f"Multiclass SVM with {kernel} kernel")       

plt.show()
```

[image: Visualization of SVM in 2-dimensions]

However, when I am going to higher dimensions, `dim > 2`, for example: `dim=10` the method `DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator` breaks and does not work. On one hand, it needs to get exactly 2 features to plot and `dim` features to predict the class. These are contradictory demands.

How do I plot SVM boundaries for higher dimensions? (say `dim=10` and `dim=200`)

Related question:
[The visualization of high-dimensional input for two-class classification in SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168285/the-visualization-of-high-dimensional-input-for-two-class-classification-in-svm)